# Node.JS + CentOS + node-waf

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

I have installed Node.JS on CentOS **from source** like this:

```
yum install gcc-c++ make git
cd /usr/local/src/
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
make install
```

yet while installing modules via **npm** I get error:

```
sh: node-waf: command not found
npm ERR! threads_a_gogo@0.1.5 install: `node-waf configure install`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure install"` failed with 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the threads_a_gogo@0.1.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the threads_a_gogo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls threads_a_gogo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

is this issue CentOS related, or what is possibly going wrong? [This](http://apphacker.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/node-waf-command-not-found/) link suggests that this error should only happen if Node is not installed from source....which in this case *it is*.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. It was working with v0.8.19 of node.js, but stopped working when I tried to install v0.10.0.

Comment: EXACTLY! I made a rollback to older version and it started working, there must be an error in the new version :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node-waf is deprecated and was removed from node 0.10: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3475.
You should open an issue with the package you are trying to use to get it updated to node-gyp.