# Node-waf: not found

Tags: node.js, npm

Here is the thing. My configuration is Ubuntu 13.04, Node.js v0.10.5 and NPM version 1.2.18.

I am trying to install node.js module "shoe" and I got this error:

```
marek@nassenfuss:/media/tc/examples/node/05.01$ sudo npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shoe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shoe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rbytes/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rbytes/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket/0.4.0

> rbytes@0.0.2 install /media/tc/examples/node/05.01/node_modules/shoe/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/rbytes
> node-waf configure build

sh: 1: node-waf: not found
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing rbytes@0.0.2
shoe@0.0.10 node_modules/shoe
├── sockjs-client@0.0.0-unreleasable
└── sockjs@0.3.1 (node-uuid@1.3.3, faye-websocket@0.4.0)
marek@nassenfuss:/media/tc/examples/node/05.01$
```

I was googling and I found that node-waf was replaced with node-gyp. I also found that node-waf can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev
```

The problem is that I am using the lastest [node.js package by Chris Lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) which does not include dev anymore. So there are two options to solve the problem.

First, I could install node-waf (from source?), but I do not how.

Second, I could (manually) repair the module, but I do not how.

I am looking for any solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024421/node-js-centos-node-waf/15979279#15979279

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`node-waf` has been replaced by `node-gyp`

Install node-gyp using:
`sudo npm install -g node-gyp`

Note: To build with node-gyp the configuration file `binding.gyp` is required.
Example:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ "src/binding.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Updating my `package.json` to use `"engines": {"npm":"1.4.x"}` fixed this for me. It had previously been `1.3.x`.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually [rbytes](https://github.com/akdubya/rbytes) that's causing the issue.

To make it even more complex: `rbytes` isn't a direct dependency for `shoe`, but for `sockjs`. And [looking at the code](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/src/utils.coffee#L120), that should function without `rbytes` too.

Since shoe declares is as an *optional* dependency, `shoe` does get installed:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing rbytes@0.0.2
         ^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So you should just be able to use it regardless of the warning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not know that I can use "shoe" despite warning. This has basically solved my problem. Anyway I still looking for answers to my two questions. Where can I get node-waf or how can I install module without NPM.

Comment: `node-waf` was deprecated with Node 0.8; its replacement, `node-gyp`, cannot build `rbytes` either (I've tried: clone the repo and use `node-gyp configure build`). If you really want to use it, you could use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install a pre-0.8 Node.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had luck getting node-waf on my machine, so I decided to fork the thing and migrate it to node-gyp so that it works.

My fork is at https://github.com/eddydas/node-sleep

To get it work, first make sure you have node-gyp by

```
$ npm install node-gyp
```

Then, clone the entire project from GitHub (either by ZIP or Git, it's up to you) and install from it.

```
$ cd ~
$ wget "https://codeload.github.com/eddydas/node-sleep/zip/master"
$ unzip master
$ cd YOUR_NODE_JS_PROJECT_FOLDER
$ npm install ~/node-sleep-master
```

I tried my best to make the thing work. If it doesn't go smooth, please feel free to let me know. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I simply upgraded my node version (from 0.4.4 into 0.6.2), problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

installing the node lts version fixed the issue for me

```
npm install n -g

sudo n lts
```