# FAILS: npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm postgres

Tags: postgresql

Tried installing the orm type for postgres

```
npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm postgres
```

But get the following error:

```
> postgres@0.0.1 install /home/kiffin/projects/coin/coin-compliancy-platform/server/node_modules/postgres
> node-waf configure build

sh: 1: node-waf: not found
```

Trying to install it:

```
npm install -g node-waf
```

or

```
npm install node-waf --save
```

doesn't help either.

Comment: are you trying to use `postgres` npm package or do you want `pg` npm package?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317976/node-waf-not-found ?