# Heroku deployment of Node application returns node-waf: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, heroku, deployment

I am attempting to deploy my Node.js application to Heroku by connecting Heroku to my Github repository and deploying the master branch.

I have tried a number of different approaches to deploy my application but all of them return the same error.

The exact build log can be found below:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.16.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.13.4
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.19.1

   Resolving node version 12.16.1...
   Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...
   npm 6.13.4 already installed with node
   Resolving yarn version 1.19.1...
   Downloading and installing yarn (1.19.1)...
   Installed yarn 1.19.1

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.19.1
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       error /tmp/build_6239d6c68cba3cabeb950e607f13b16d/node_modules/node-base64: Command failed.
       Exit code: 127
       Command: ./install.sh
       Arguments: 
       Directory: /tmp/build_6239d6c68cba3cabeb950e607f13b16d/node_modules/node-base64
       Output:
       ./install.sh: 3: ./install.sh: node-waf: not found
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/

   Love,
   Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

My `package.json` file can be found below:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4",
    "yarn": "1.19.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt": "^0.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.11",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.5",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.32",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1"
  }
}
```

- I have tried adding the exact engine versions to the package.json.
- I have tried removing yarn.lock.
- I have tried installing typescript as a dependency instead as a global package.
- I don't know how I can manually install the node-base64/node-waf dependency.

Thank you for all your potential solutions.

Comment: It appears you are using yarn and npm together. Is there any reason why you can't use only yarn, at least on your heroku env? This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589493/is-there-any-harm-in-using-npm-and-yarn-in-the-same-project.

Comment: Nice catch, there is no reason to why I shouldn't be able to use only yarn. I started this project on a different device than I am currently using (that is why yarn and npm got mixed up). I have tried looking for a package-lock.json file but it does not exist, however, the yarn.lock file does exist but I had already tried to remove this file before and it did not help me. Are there any other files which tell Heroku to use NPM? Should I perhaps remove the npm engine declaration from the package.json file?

Comment: Actually, looking deeper into your package.json and the error log, I figured the problem is coming from `jwt`. You can try using `jsonwebtoken` instead of `jwt`. If that works, let me know so I can make it an answer to help others who might have similar issue.

Comment: I have removed the jwt package and the deployment succeeded. I can recall that I tried to use jwt before but switched to jsonwebtoken after, you can tell by looking at my package.json. Thank you very much for your help, I genuinely can't understand how you've found out that that was the issue? Your answer did solve my question so you can make it answer.

Comment: Happy it helped you get unblocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR. Remove `jwt` and use `jsonwebtoken`.

Details:
[jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt) has [node-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-base64) as a dependency. Both jwt and node-base64 are no longer maintained. Under the hood, node-base64 uses `node-waf` which is already deprecated. So, this loop of calls to deprecated packages resulted to the failure you encountered. Replacing `jwt` with `jsonwebtoken` will solve this issue.

It's also possible to encounter issues with `node-waf` without using jwt. See this Stackoverflow question [Node-waf: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317976/node-waf-not-found) to help you with that.